# SQL Query for getting next day forecasts from Postgres table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

The table below contains rows of forecast data.  A forecast arrives twice an hour.  That forecast will contain 7 days of data, 24 hours for each day.  I want an effective way to query the table and only get the forecast from 14:10 (forecasts come in at :10 and :45 each hour) and only for the day following the forecast (not the 6 additional days)

```
CREATE TABLE
    forecast_table
    (
        forecast_timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        forecast_date DATE NOT NULL,
        forecast_hour INTEGER NOT NULL,
        number_value NUMERIC NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (forecast_timestamp, forecast_date , forecast_hour )
    );
```

For example I'd like all the 24 hour forecasts for each day between Jan-1-2014 and Feb-1-2014.  These have to be the 14:10 forecasts from the previous day.

I feel there must be an efficient way to query this table and only get the 24 hours for each day that I need.

Comment: I'm unclear.  Do you want one forecast per day (the one at 14:10)?  Or do you want all 24 hours of forecasts with some additional column?

Comment: The forecast is a set of 24 hours (so there are 48 x 24 rows inserted daily).  I'd like the set of 24 hours that were inserted at 14:10, each day.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you're looking for, mainly because there are many dates and times in your table, and it's not clear what the data actually looks like or what the results should look like.

There's [all kinds of date and time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html) that you can use.

This should list all forecasts with a time of 14:10, took place in the month of January 2014, and when issued were meant to forecast a date less than 1 day in the future.  There's about a dozen ways to write this, and you'll need to play around to find a good one.  If you can find a way to write it such that your fields aren't in functions, that would be best.

```
SELECT *
FROM forecast_table
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM forecast_timestamp) = 14
    AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM forecast_timestamp) = 10
    AND forecast_timestamp > forecast_date - interval '1 day'  
    AND date_trunc('month', forecast_date) = timestamp '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

I can't tell if you want the `forecast_hours` field to be counted against the 24 hours limitation you want applied to `forecast_timestamp`.  If you do:

```
SELECT *
FROM forecast_table
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM forecast_timestamp) = 14
    AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM forecast_timestamp) = 10
    AND forecast_timestamp > (forecast_date + (forecast_hour * '1 hour'::interval)) - interval '1 day'  
    AND date_trunc('month', forecast_date) = timestamp '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Truly, the `forecast_hour` field really ought to be of data type `interval hour` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thanks @bacon-bits, I'll play around with this.  I hadn't considered using an interval hour as I hadn't actually heard of this datatype before.  Thanks.